# Cannot Check if the Access Database Engine is Installed and Configured

Tags: sql-server-2008, linked-server

All, I want to check if the Access Database Engine is installed and linked to SQL Server. On my development machine (x64-bit) the following queries both show the Access Engine to be available as a linked server:

```
SELECT srv.provider
FROM sys.servers As srv 
WHERE is_linked = 1;
```

and

```
EXEC sp_linkedservers;
```

but these do not work (that is they do not return the Access Engine as a linked server - it is though) on another x64-bit machine. Why?